# Parameters in QueryBuilder (Doctrine/Symfony)

Tags: symfony, parameters, doctrine

I have this code:

```
    $sort = (is_null($sort)) ? 'i.name' : $sort;
    $order = (!is_null($order) && $order == 'ASC') ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';

    $queryBuilder
        ->select('s')
        ->from('Model:Item', 'i')
        ->where('i.isRemoved = false')
        ->orderBy(':sort', $order)
        ->setParameter('sort', $sort);
```

But I get this error:

```
[1/2] QueryException: SELECT i FROM Model:Item i WHERE i.isRemoved = false ORDER BY :sort DESC
```

I must be doing something wrong with the `setParameter()` call, but I can't figure out what?

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Doctrine will not use a parameter in the orderBy method. The parameters are reserved for the where, andWhere, orWhere methods. Thomas Kelly's answer is a good workaround for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setParameter()` is used to prevent SQL injection attacks, since many `WHERE` clauses rely on user input.

And this might be the cause of the problem here -- I'm not entirely sure that the `ORDER BY` clause supports parameter replacement. I may be wrong on that, but your error seems to indicate that either (1) it doesn't support it, or (2) you're getting bad input.

Where exactly are you getting your `$sort` from? If it's coming from some user input, then you might want to perform the sanitization logic here instead, and just set the resolved value in the `orderBy()` method.

Consider an example where `id` and `name` are actual fields. What happens when someone tries to pass in `i.description`? The entire SQL would fail. But not if you did something like this:

```
$sort = (in_array($sort, array('i.id', 'i.name')))
    ? $sort
    : 'i.name';

// Now you've effectively sanitized the value
// i.e. It's *always* going to be either 'i.id' or 'i.name'
// So there's no reason to need something like setParameter()

$queryBuilder
        ->select('s')
        ->from('Model:Item', 'i')
        ->where('i.isRemoved = false')
        ->orderBy($sort);
```